# Escape % sign in numpy format string

Tags: python, numpy

I would appreciate some help. Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import numpy as np

x = np.array(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'])
y = np.array([10.0, 15.0, 25.0])
records_array = np.core.records.fromarrays([x, y])
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, records_array, fmt='%s %.1f')
```

gives (as expected):

```
aaa 10.0
bbb 15.0
ccc 25.0
```

**To print the last column as percent, I changed the last line to:**

```
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, records_array, fmt='%s %.1f %%')
```

but got the following error message:

```
File "./savetxt_percent.py", line 9, in <module>
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, records_array, fmt='%s %.1f %%')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1055, in savetxt
raise error
ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %s %.1f %%
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strange that the % does not get interpreted correctly.  When you use a string for `fmt` it must parse it.  I have not looked at the code carefully but it must get confused when trying to split the string on '%' characters to count the number of things to print.  To work around this the `fmt` argument to `np.savetxt` can also be specified as a pre-split list.  In other words, you can use

```
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, records_array, fmt=['%s', '%.1f %%'])
```

This will work for any number/location of '%' you want in your output.

Comment: Pretty cool, I wasn't familiar with the option to specify the fmt as a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to print a `%` symbol, escape it with a back slash `\`:

```
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, records_array, fmt='%s %.1f \%')
```